IIS server Issue Cors using angular and asp.net core application
I'm encountering a CORS issue on my IIS server where my Angular application is unable to communicate with the API and retrieve responses after a few hours of uptime, but restarting the IIS server temporarily resolves the issue. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this problem?
I want to know how to solve the issue on IIS server if any one know please help

If you haven't installed and configured IIS CORS module, the cause is very clear. https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Please make sure you have installed and configured the CORS module in iis, you can use this link as a reference: IIS CORS module Configuration Reference.
